# How do I view my website stats via cmd line?

Tags: logging

I use Wordpress for my website. Is it possible to use SSH or such to view the stats on my website? Via cPanel, I can see latest visitors, logs and errors. I just want to be able to view them via command line (more geeky). I am using the latest OS X.

Comment: If you want to be geeky, don't rely on cPanel and set up a server the same way the rest of us do? :)

Comment: Buying a hosting plan is the best I can do ATM. Anyway, is it possible?

Comment: You're at the mercy of the hosting provider with respect to log files, then. And I've seen some strange cPanel setups where the log files are split _by directory_, making them pretty much impossible to deal with. Anyway, the answer is, contact your hosting provider for log file access.

Comment: @john What kind of stats are you looking for?  The web server logs are going to be a lot more in-depth than a high-level view of visitor's sessions, since every HTTP request for every resource on a page is displayed individually, and not grouped by client IP or session.  Anyway, this is worth a mention, as it ups the 'geeky' level of those raw logs by at least a few points: http://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/

Comment: I can see the log files from cPanel. I just want to be able to access them with another application rather than using cPanel. Like see them real time.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest the Lynx web browser, as it is run in the command line. Check out the project site at [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/). Anyhow, I agree with Micheal in that you should stop using Cpanel should you want to be "geeky". Also there are several programs that can give you a MUCH better insight to your "stats" through a GUI browser such as Google Analytics or AWstats.

Comment: Is it possible to have my terminal window open and just see the daily traffic on the website?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it on OS X, but I've had good luck with [`GoAccess`](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/download) on CentOS. I have a cron job that uses GoAccess to dump my logs out to HTML (automatically done by redirecting a goaccess command to a file) and puts them in a private directory.